How can i check a file on azure blob storage is editing or not?
I am facing a problem that I have a text file on blob storage of azure. suppose when a user open and editing that file (not save) in other thread and how can I know that ?
Currently I am exploring an idea like when I start editing a file update the metadata with the status key as 'editing' and remove it when done. and based on this metadata to determine if the file is in the process of being modified or not? but I really think there will be a better solution in azure ?

IIRC the only option is blob leases, which, of course, requires all clients cooperate. Also, I've never found a way to query for a lease other than trying to acquire one.

Azure blobs are not files and can't be opened for editing (unless you're explicitly using an Azure Files share). You can append to an existing blob (assuming you're using append blobs), but otherwise, any editing would be in your app (download to app, modify, re-upload). And you'd need to lock the blob during that time (e.g. a lease, as mentioned in another comment)

fyi - for clarity - this question is off-topic as written - you're asking opinions on how to handle updates to blob, and with no specific programming question. Please read [ask]


Currently I am exploring an idea like when I start editing a file update the metadata with the status key as 'editing' and remove it when done. and based on this metadata to determine if the file is in the process of being modified or not? but I really think there will be a better solution in azure ?

Azure Blob Storage does not provide a built-in feature to track whether a file is being edited or not. However, you mentioned in metadata for editing with key and value is not great choice for multiple purposes, when multiple users are trying to add the metadata, simultaneously it became race condition.
I agree with David Makagon's and richard's comment,

You can download the file to your application, modify it, and then upload it back to Azure Blob Storage.
To prevent multiple users from editing the same file at the same time, you can use a lease on the blob. While the lease is active, no other client can modify the blob.

Here is code that the creates lease, download the blob, edit the text file, reupload and release the lease from file.
Code:
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;
using Azure;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "xxxxx";
        string containerName = "data";
        string blobName = "file1.txt";
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

        BlobLeaseClient leaseClient = blobClient.GetBlobLeaseClient();
        string leaseId = null;
        try
        {
            // Acquire a 60 seconds lease
            Response<BlobLease> lease = leaseClient.Acquire(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            leaseId = lease.Value.LeaseId;
            Console.WriteLine($"Lease acquired with ID: {leaseId}");

            // Perform editing operations here
            BlobDownloadInfo download = blobClient.Download();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(download.Content, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine($"File content before edit: {content}");

                // Example of editing the file
                string newContent = content + "\nNew line added.";
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newContent)))
                {
                    BlobRequestConditions conditions = new BlobRequestConditions { LeaseId = leaseId };
                    blobClient.Upload(
                        content: stream,
                        httpHeaders: null,
                        metadata: null,
                        conditions: conditions,
                        accessTier: null,
                        cancellationToken: default
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        catch (RequestFailedException ex) when (ex.ErrorCode == BlobErrorCode.LeaseAlreadyPresent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Blob is already leased by another process. Cannot acquire lease.");
        }
        catch (RequestFailedException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (leaseId != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Release the lease
                    leaseClient.Release();
                    Console.WriteLine("Lease released.");
                }
                catch (RequestFailedException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while releasing the lease: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:
Lease acquired with ID: 0604a179-xxxxx-4811-9091-1a522dbefc7f
File content before edit: The sun dipped below the horizon, painting the sky in hues of orange and pink as the evening unfolded. The soft rustling of leaves in the gentle breeze created a soothing symphony, blending with the distant hum of city life. A family of ducks glided gracefully across the tranquil lake, their reflections shimmering on the still water. Nearby, the scent of blooming jasmine filled the air, mingling with the earthy aroma of freshly mowed grass. As night began to fall, stars started to twinkle, casting their celestial glow over the serene landscape, inviting a sense of calm and wonder.
New line added.
Lease released.

Portal:

Reference:
Create and manage blob leases with .NET - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn

The question has zero code, and no specific programming question. Stack Overflow is not for posting requirements and receiving custom code solutions (which is exactly what you did). Please don't do this. Also, you called out my comment in your answer - the comment was all that was needed. You also made an assumption that the OP works with C# by providing C# code (this was never mentioned anywhere - not even in a tag) - and your link is specific to C#. Tl;dr please just close-vote off-topic questions, and help improve questions by posting comments where needed.
